# Quickblox: Only receive the correct messages

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, quickblox

I am developing a chat using quickblox but I am having some problems when I open a new chat. Suddenly I received all the messages that others users sends to me when I was disconnected. The problem is that when I start a chat with user A, I receive the chats from users B, C, D.. in user A chat room.

I have find the way to only show the A users. But the problem is that the server has already sent to me the "disconnected" messages, so when I start a chat to B I do not receive any text because the message that the user B sent to me has been delivered (and omitted) while I was chatting with user A.

How can I do to receive the pending messages (kind of history) or to just retrieve the message of the chat I am logged in?

A piece of my code:

```
private MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

        System.out.println("CridaC");

         String from = message.getFrom().split("@")[0];
            String to = message.getTo().split("@")[0];

            System.out.println(String.format(">>> Message received (from=%s, to=%s): %s",from, to, message.getBody()));

//              return;

        if (onMessageReceivedListener != null && message.getBody() != null) {
            System.out.println("CridaD");

            onMessageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(message);
        }
    }
};
```

Does anybody know I way to deploy a chat in a few steps?

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behaviour. You will receive all the messages from all the users after just login. Doesn't matter if you are now in the Chat with user A.

Possible solution - store all new messages into the ArrayList, HashMap.
When you open a chat with user B - just retrieve messages from user B from this ArrayList/ HashMap and show them in your screen.

Comment: I have implemented an internal Data Base to solve that situation. Now the behaviour is desired. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get chat dialog for this particular user for which you wants to get history.
Actually when two users starting chat at first time, a dialog is created for them to perform chat. They will always chat under this dialog. Dialog you can say is a kind of platform to chat. Dialog also has a dialog id. Quickblox provided a function to create dialog on behalf of friendID whom you wanna chat(You need to pass friendID into this function). If this is the first time chat, this function creates a dialogId for you and if you have performed a chat before then existing dialog ID is returned. After getting this dialogID, you are able to get chat history with the help of this dialogID.

Conclusion : You can only get chat history by dialogID.

Here is the code :

1.) Create a chatManager object.

2.) Create your custom message object by using QuickBlox QBChatMessage object :

```
public class ChatMessageModel {
    private Integer id;
    private String body;
    private Collection<Integer> readIds;
    private Integer recipientId;
    private String nameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived;
    private String messageId;
    private Integer senderId;
    private String message;
    private String dialogId;
    private long time;
    private boolean isMessageSelected=false; //true if user selects an item or copy or delete and vice versa

    public boolean isMessageSelected() {
        return isMessageSelected;
    }

    public void setIsMessageSelected(boolean isMessageSelected) {
        this.isMessageSelected = isMessageSelected;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }
    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public Integer getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(Integer senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public String getNameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived() {
        return nameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived;
    }

    public void setNameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived(String nameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived) {
        this.nameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived = nameToDisplayOnlyWhenAMessageIsReceived;
    }


    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

//    public Collection<Integer> getReadIds() {
//        return readIds;
//    }

    public void setReadIds(Collection<Integer> readIds) {
        this.readIds = readIds;
    }

    public Integer getRecipientId() {
        return recipientId;
    }

    public void setRecipientId(Integer recipientId) {
        this.recipientId = recipientId;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getDialogId() {
        return dialogId;
    }

    public void setDialogId(String dialogId) {
        this.dialogId = dialogId;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //    return super.equals(o);
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != ChatMessageModel.class) {
            return false;
        }
        ChatMessageModel other = (ChatMessageModel) obj;
        if (other.messageId != this.messageId) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    //    return super.hashCode();
        return messageId == null ? 0 : messageId.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return messageId;
    }
}
```

3.) Function to get chat history :

```
public void getChatHistoryForDialog(Integer otherUserId, final Integer numberOfMessages) {

        final ArrayList<ChatMessageModel> myList = new ArrayList<ChatMessageModel>();

        privateChatManager.createDialog(otherUserId, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
                requestBuilder.sortAsc("last_message_date_sent");
                requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(numberOfMessages.intValue());// limit of max messages fetch from server
                QBChatService.getDialogMessages(dialog, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBChatMessage>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages, Bundle args) {
                        for (QBChatMessage message : messages) {
                            ChatMessageModel model = new ChatMessageModel();
                            model.setIsMessageSelected(false);
                            model.setId(message.getSenderId());
                            model.setMessageId(message.getId());
                            model.setMessage(message.getBody());
                            message.setMarkable(true);
                            model.setTime(message.getDateSent() * 1000L);// Multiplied by 1000L because the time given by Quickblox server is epoch time
                            model.setReadIds(message.getReadIds());
                            model.setRecipientId(message.getRecipientId());
                            model.setDialogId(dialog.getDialogId());
                            myList.add(model);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            }
        });

    }
```